# Distorted HTML content using selenium get_attribute

Tags: python, selenium, innerhtml, getattribute

I am trying to get the `innerHTML` of an element using:

```
de_nc = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('element').get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

But i get the following:

```
<a href=""https://****/""><u>Text</u></a>
```

Instead of the following:

```
<a href="https://****/"><u><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Text</font></font></u></a>
```

Comment: is the font element generated dynamically?

Comment: We are going to need to input daya to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `outerHTML` attribute so it will return the HTML of the element itself with all the children elements. try this:

```
de_nc = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('element').get_attribute("outerHTML")
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the `innerHTML` of an element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Comment: This does not solve. I already tried with `WebDriverWait` too.